# Is there an easier way to slice a VDB object?

Tags: 3d-view, volumetrics

In the solid view, VDB objects have this amazing slider view that lets you view slices along an axis of the volume.

[image]
[image]

However, this doesn't work in render view.

Is there a more intuitive way of doing this than my current setup?
[image]
[image]